# How is precedence determined in C pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I've come across two pointer declarations that I'm having trouble understanding. My understanding of precedence rules goes something like this:

```
Operator             Precedence             Associativity
(), [ ]                  1                  Left to Right
*, identifier            2                  Right to Left
Data type                3
```

But even given this, I can't seem to figure out how to evaluate the following examples correctly:

#### First example

```
float * (* (*ptr)(int))(double **,char c)
```

My evaluation:

1. `*(ptr)`
2. `(int)`
3. `*(*ptr)(int)`
4. `*(*(*ptr)(int))`

Then,

1. `double **`
2. `char c`

#### Second example

```
unsigned **( * (*ptr) [5] ) (char const *,int *)
```

1. `*(ptr)`
2. `[5]`
3. `*(*ptr)[5]`
4. `*(*(*ptr)[5])`
5. `**(*(*ptr)[5])`

How *should* I read them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**My guess for the first one**: ptr is a pointer to a function that takes as parameter an int, and returns a pointer to a function that takes as parameters a pointer to pointer to double and a char, and returns a pointer to float.

**Interpretation**:

(*ptr)(int)

says that ptr is a pointer to a function taking an int as an argument. To discover what that function returns we need to expand our view:

(* (*ptr)(int))

this means the function returns a pointer to another function. The parameters of that other function are:

(double **,char c)

and it returns

float *

**And for the second one**: ptr is a pointer to an array of five pointers to functions that take as parameters a constant pointer to char and a pointer to int, returning a pointer to a pointer of unsigned int.

**Interpretation**:

( * (*ptr) [5] )

declares ptr as a pointer to array of five pointers to a function taking

(char const *,int *)

as arguments and returning

unsigned **

Answer (score 7):

You could try the 'The Clockwise Spiral' Method to understand these insane declarations:

http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

I blogged about it here too:

http://www.kalekold.net/index.php?post=4

Comment: Thank you for reply. But in The Clockwise Spiral method from where to start in my case? In the examples given on the link there are simple examples. I am not able to match my equation with that method.

Comment: you should start from your identifier: ptr. you will have: "ptr is a pointer to a function that takes an int and returns a pointer to a function that takes a pointer to a pointer to a double and a char and returns a pointer to a float". try the spyral and you'll get the same.

Answer (score 2):

Using cdecl.org:

> char * const (* (* const bar)[5])(int )

[declare bar as const pointer to array 5 of pointer to function (int) returning const pointer to char](http://cdecl.org/?q=char+%2a+const+%28%2a%28%2a+const+bar%29%5b5%5d%29%28int+%29)

> unsigned **( * (*ptr) [5] ) ( char const *,int *)

[declare ptr as pointer to array 5 of pointer to function (pointer to const char, pointer to int) returning pointer to pointer to unsigned](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=unsigned+%2a%2a%28+%2a+%28%2apt%29+%5b5%5d+%29+%28const+char++%2a%2Cint+%2a%29)

Answer (score 1):

It's a function pointer.   The person who wrote it could have made better use of typedefs to have made it clearer.

It is in effect a pointer to function with these parameters.
    float* myfunc(double**, char)

Comment: My bet is that the person who wrote it is the teacher.

Comment: Lets hope it isn't the teacher, because you don't need to know crap like this. Though I suppose a good teacher would first slap you in the face with expressions like these, letting you scratch your head trying to interpret them, _then_ show you how to use typedef properly.